# Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK v4: MissingMethodException

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, .net-5

I am running Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK v4 (Azure Cosmos 4.0.0-preview3) in Azure Function App in .NET5.

```
         CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClientBuilder(account, key)
                .Build();
```

Above code throws error:

```
An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Azure.Cosmos.dll but was not handled in user code
Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.Azure.Documents.IAuthorizationTokenProvider.GetUserAuthorizationToken(System.String, System.String, System.String, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Collections.INameValueCollection, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.AuthorizationTokenType, System.String ByRef)'.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: have you tried this https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2038 ?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the Cosmos client with AccountEndpoint, Account Key or Resource token and should be configure with required region.

```
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(
"account-endpoint-from-portal",
 "account-key-from-portal",
 new CosmosClientOptions()
 {      ApplicationRegion = Regions.EastUS2     });
```

The CosmosClient is created through builder pattern using .

```
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClientBuilder("connection-string-from-portal")
.WithApplicationRegion("East US 2")
.Build();
```

Try with the above code.

This [github code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/CosmosClient.cs), [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-sql-api-dotnet-v4#code-try-0)  helped me to deploy .net console application on azure using cosmos db without error.

For more information like troubleshooting issues when using azure cosmos DB .NET SDK, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk?tabs=diagnostics-v3).